# If I use an 8 speed bar end shifter with the TT bar on my Allez, will I need to change any other parts of the drive chain?

Tags: shifter, cassette, front

My current bicycle is a 2013 Specialized Allez C2. It has an 8 speed rear cassette. I'd like to put in a TT handlebar. It's a given that I'll have to change the brake levers, as well as the shifters and associated cables. Now, I spoke with a repair guy at Cynergy Cycles, and he said that there are no 8 speed front end bar shifters, so pretty much the whole drive chain would have to be replaced… I looked it up and found only one: a [Shimano Ultegra SL-BS64 Shifter](http://www.outsideoutfitters.com/p-27921-shimano-ultegra-sl-bs64-shifter-road-pairs.aspx?variantID=91802&gclid=CPre5t-81MACFRVufgodwzUA5w). Would that pretty much do the job? or would anything else need to be changed as well?

Comment: Have you thought about the geometry impact? Road bikes have a longer top tube than TT bikes so can be quite far to reach. I've just about gotten away with clip-on aero bars on my Tarmac after sliding the seat all the way forward. Though I've only put on for triathlons and then taken them off again.

Comment: That would explain the original poster's other [question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/24592/will-bending-the-seat-post-two-inches-forward-cause-any-unforeseen-structural-is).

Comment: You should probably find a new mechanic. That guy is either too lazy or incompetent to find you the part you need, or he just straight-up lied to you to sell you more parts. Whichever the case, he doesn't deserve your business.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any 8 speed Shimano-compatible bar end shifter will work if you're running a Shimano drive train (If you're running SRAM, you'd obviously need a SRAM compatible one).

Those will work, as will the ones from Microshift 8 speed among others. You'll need to re-run your cables, obviously, though.

Comment: Another option if you don't find the right bar end shifter is to just throw a higher speed cassette on there then get a compatible bar end shifter. The derailleurs don't need to change.

Comment: You can run SRAM by using the 8-speed bar end shifter in friction mode (without indexing).  Most bar end shifters have this mode (except for the 10+ speed Shimano bar end shifters).