# Is there a gadget that will let me slide my seat forward more than my post allows?

Tags: saddle, seatpost, triathlon

So I'm I'm trying to dial in the fit on my road bike to be more tri-bike like, and in doing so, I'd like to move my seat forward, well, more than I currently can.

I have the [Redshift seatpost](http://www.redshiftsports.com/dual-position-seatpost/), and I really like the dual position action, but it just doesn't go far enough forward for me to hit my ideal position. Truth be told, my bike doesn't fit me as well as it should, but it's currently a better option for me to try to make it work than find a new bike.

Anyway, in my searches I came across the [M2Racer Power Module](http://www.togoparts.com/articles/article.php?artid=115) which was apparently a product about a decade ago. It looks like exactly the part I'd like to have, but I can't find anybody selling one. Alternatively, is there anything else out there that would give me a similar effect?

For what it's worth, I've investigated flipping around a setback seatpost, but the Redshift goes forward further, and I've seen the Profile Design FastForward, but I don't think it will give me much more than my current setup.

Comment: Not a duplicate but answers address some of your question.  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/24592/will-bending-the-seat-post-two-inches-forward-cause-any-unforeseen-structural-is/24600#24600  Not that I know of any but look for seats with longer rails.

Comment: I saw that thread.  I'm not wanting to bend the seatpost.  Seems too risky.  As for finding a new saddle, well, I really like my saddle.

Comment: And that is why I said "Not a duplicate but answers address some of your question".  So no chance of finding another seat that fits you?

Comment: The Velo Orange grand Cru seatpost might be an option.Theres also something called a lay back seatpost which if you installed backwards would probably give you the most forward movement possible (though obviously, ymmv regarding safety and what not).

Comment: Also, have you tried a different stem which would move the bars back?

Comment: My concern is not so much for reach.  I can tweak the stem length for that, of course.   At the moment, I'm more concerned with moving my hips closer to 12 o'clock of the crank.

Comment: You could try a [different slider seatpost](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=seatpost+with+adjustable+setback) and flip it so it's shifting the saddle forward rather than backward, which would give you maybe 20mm more shift than you have, but as you say, the post you have is already pretty extreme. The first two in that search seem to maybe give a little more range.

Answer (score 3):

No. Based on your question and your comments, there is not a product that does what you are seeking (get your hips over the bottom bracket). The reason being that no one rides that far forward.<sup>1</sup> The old style Profile is probably your best bet for getting forward:

[image]

There are designs with a seat over the bottom bracket, even some that are made super-adjustable in that regard:

[image]

Even at that far forward, the hips are behind the bottom bracket:

[image]

With that in mind, a reason that most people don't ride that far forward is because moving yourself that far forward screws with the bicycle handling and puts you too far over the front wheel. Note that bikes that enable the most aero positions, like those pictured above, achieve the effect not by moving the saddle forward, but by moving the bottom bracket back.

Now, with all that lecturing done, I would say that if you are dedicated to this experiment, you can get close with the profile seatpost mentioned and an ISM saddle. The ISM is an anatomical design with two points and a gap between. A lot of riders slide forward on that saddle and hook their sitbones on the two points. This is opposed to traditional time trial saddles which just had more padding on the nose meaning that sliding forward just jams that thing into you perineum. Even better is if you can start with a bike with a steeper seat tube.

<sup>1</sup>That is a bit of hyperbole, perhaps someone rides that far forward.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem over 20 years ago....I went to a metal engineering place and designed my own for them to make..You can see i managed to go 8cm forward before tri bikes were made.[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  But what was the gadget?  Do you have photographs of the part itself, or better, plan drawings of it?