Seat post doesn’t allow seat to move forward enough; my legs have to reach forward to pedal
I bought a e-bike made for 5ft to 6ft tall person, I’m 5ft.  I can reach the pedals and can pedal.  However, the seat position isn’t over my pedals, to really pedal I’m reaching in front of my body to make the pedals go round.  Is there anything out there to help move the seat position forward so the pedals are under me a bit?

Does this answer your question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36160/is-there-a-gadget-that-will-let-me-slide-my-seat-forward-more-than-my-post-allow  - If you have a standard seatpost on your e-bike (round and a common diameter) there may be forward leaning options out there (may end up too tall for a smaller fit to a frame like yours). From your question, I am assuming that you have already slid your current saddle as far forward as the seatpost and saddle rails will allow. A different saddle that allows a little more forward movement (linger rails) may be an option as well.

Sounds like you may have a pedal forward design that is intended to make the bike a bit more roomy for the rider.

Maybe you could find someone to take a picture of you on the bike. That might make it easier to assess the situation you're in.

I wonder if this is a cruiser frame, or a crank-forward frame ?  Something like https://watermanstore.co.nz/cdn/shop/products/MaverickCruiser.png    ?   OP please post a photo of your bike, or a link to the model.

Would you be able to attach a picture? Feel free to blur out your face if you'd like.

Edit: This answer only applies to road bikes and other upright bikes which are designed for efficient pedaling. It won’t apply to downhill mountain-bikes, cruiser bikes or (obviously) recumbents which are designed to have their saddle/seat much further back.

Very roughly the tip of your saddle should be slightly behind the bottom bracket (the point your cranks rotate around).
A better rule of thumb is that your kneecap should be over the pedal spindle in the 3'o clock position. https://www.bicycling.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/bicycle_saddle_plumb_line.jpg
You should be able to adjust the saddle’s fore/aft position by loosening the saddle clamp and sliding it forwards or backwards. Most seatposts have “setback” of around 20mm (they are “bent” backwards by ~20mm at the very top). If you can’t move forward far enough with such a normal seatpost, there are zero setback seatposts which don’t have this bend.

Some bikes are designed to have the feet further forward so it is easier to get your feet on the ground and still have a good distance for your legs when cycling.

The other possibility is its a casual ebike intended to sit-on more than pedalling?
